# First occurrence of the Langevin function in scientific literature

Tags: physics, reference-request, magnetism

The Langevin function $\mathcal{L}(x) = \mathrm{coth}(x) - \frac{1}{x}$ is named after the French physicist [Paul Langevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Langevin) (1872-1946).
The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_and_Langevin_functions) on the Brillouin and Langevin functions does not cite a publication by Langevin and other sources I consulted merely indicate that it originates in Langevin's work on paramagnetism.

In which publication by Langevin did this function make its first appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I could determine after searching for a couple of hours, this function was first introduced in the following publication, a [scan](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k34935p/f68.item) of which is made available by the Bibliothèque nationale de France:

P. Langevin, "Magnétisme et théorie des électrons," *Annales de chimie et de physique*, 8:5 (1905), 70-127.

On [page 117](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k34935p/f115.item) one finds:

> Le moment magnétique total des $\mathrm{N}$ molécules est évidemment
> dirigé parallèlement au champ et est égal à la somme des projections
> sur cette direction des moments composants. Pour l'unité de volume
> supposée contenir $\mathrm{N}$ molécules, ce moment résultant
> représente l'intensité d'aimantation $\mathrm{I}$ :
>
> $$\mathrm{I}=\int{\mathrm{M}\cos \alpha}{\ dn} = \int_{-1}^{+1}{2\pi\mathrm{MK\ }x\ e^{ax}\ {dx}}.$$
> Or
> $$\int_{-1}^{+1}{x\ }{e^{ax}}{\ dx} = 2 \left(\frac{\mathrm{Ch\ } {a}}{a}-\frac{\mathrm{Sh\ }a}{a^{2}}\right),$$
> d'où $$\mathrm{I}=\mathrm{MN}\left(\frac{\mathrm{Ch\ }a}{\mathrm{Sh\
>  }{a}}-\frac{1}{a}\right).$$

Here $\mathrm{Ch}$ represents the hyperbolic cosine and $\mathrm{Sh}$ the hyperbolic sine, thus $\mathrm{I}=\mathrm {MN}\left(\mathrm{coth}(a) - \frac{1}{a}\right) = \mathrm{MN}\mathcal{L}(a).$